# condition on print in an awk if statment

Tags: if-statement, printing, awk

I'm working on a little code with awk: I'm looking for a pattern and if its find I would like to print the newt 3 lines. Without an if, no problem:

```
awk '/\/1/ {x=NR+3}(NR<=x) {print > "out"}' input
```

the file I use:

```
@_5:1:7:9569:21200/1  
CAGAATGCCGTGGAACTGAAACGTCTGGC
+  
CCCFFFFFHHHHHJJJJIJJIHIJJIJJI
@_5:1:7:9569:21200/2
GCACCATCATCACCGGTTCCGGGCAGCGC
+  
CCCFFFFFHHFHHJJJGHJJJJJJJIGGI
@_5:1:11:12099:7543/1  
CAGAATGCCGTGGAACTGAAACGTCTGGC
```

I would like to separate this file in two others as follow

```
File 1
@_5:1:7:9569:21200/1  
CAGAATGCCGTGGAACTGAAACGTCTGGC
+  
CCCFFFFFHHHHHJJJJIJJIHIJJIJJI
@_5:1:11:12099:7543/1  
CAGAATGCCGTGGAACTGAAACGTCTGGC

File 2
 @_5:1:7:9569:21200/2
GCACCATCATCACCGGTTCCGGGCAGCGC
+  
CCCFFFFFHHFHHJJJGHJJJJJJJIGGI
```

But with the if I have syntax error on the print

```
awk '{ if (/\/1/) {x=NR+3}(NR<=x) {print > "file1"};} else (/\/2/) {x=NR+3}(NR<=x) {print > "file2"}' "input_file"
```

If someone has an idea to fix that

Thanks!

Comment: Give example data and what you like to get out of it.

Comment: Done, edit first message ^^

Comment: Take care that there are space after your number in the text file.

Comment: Why do people insist on writing one-line `awk` programs that should be spread over multiple lines for readability if nothing else?  It isn't just you, Marwai; it is a lot of people, most of whom should know better.  You can perfectly well write an `awk` script using normal layout rules.  If someone submitted a one-line Java program or C program for review, it would be rejected as unreadable (and/or implausible because of `#include` directives in C), but the concept applies — this is a programming language and sensible coding conventions should be followed.

Comment: Lol, I know its not against me, and I agree with you. Unfortunately it was for a programming challenge for a job.

Answer (score 1):

Some like this:

```
awk -F"/" '/^@/ {f=$2} {print > ("file"f+0)}' data
```

Need to add the `+0` to remove space after the line.

```
cat file1
@_5:1:7:9569:21200/1
CAGAATGCCGTGGAACTGAAACGTCTGGC
+
CCCFFFFFHHHHHJJJJIJJIHIJJIJJI
@_5:1:11:12099:7543/1
CAGAATGCCGTGGAACTGAAACGTCTGGC
```

```
cat file2
@_5:1:7:9569:21200/2
GCACCATCATCACCGGTTCCGGGCAGCGC
+
CCCFFFFFHHFHHJJJGHJJJJJJJIGGI
```

Using `-F/` divide line into `$1` and `$2` by the separator `/`
 
`{f=$2}` store the last digit of line starting with `@`
Then data is written to `"file"f"` so when f=1, it would be `file1` etc.

Comment: thanks for your answer, unfortunately it write only the matching line (and it works in an if statement), my problem is to write also the 3 next.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just have a little question: I am beginner in bash and I don't understand how this line can create two differents file. Is because of f=$2?

Comment: Updated my answer to give some info.

Comment: +1; note that FreeBSD awk (e.g., on OSX) requires parentheses around `"file"f+0`.

Comment: @mklement0 updated my answer to make it more portable.

Comment: @Jotne: Thanks, but - surprisingly - it needs to be `("file"f+0)` (parentheses around the _whole_ string expression) to work on OSX.